# Building a dynamic where clause for dynamic keywords or using IQueryable C# Linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, iqueryable

I am trying to write a dynamic where clause using LINQ for returning all rows that contain any keyword supplied in an string array. The results do not come back as expected with what I have so far and looking at the SQL I can see the problem.

```
IQueryable<comments> query = _db.comments;

if (score != null)
    query = query.Where(x => x.score == score);
if (dateFrom != null)3
    query = query.Where(x => x.date_created >= dateFrom);
if (dateTo != null)
    query = query.Where(x => x.date_created <= dateTo);
if (keywords != null)
{
    //how to use OR for each in array?
    foreach (var keyword in keywords)
    {
        var keywordCondition = keyword;
        query = query.Where(x => x.text.Contains(keywordCondition));  
    }

}

WHERE ([Extent1].[score] = @p__linq__0) 
AND ([Extent1].[date_created] >= @p__linq__1) 
AND ([Extent1].[date_created] <= @p__linq__2) 
AND ([Extent1].[text] LIKE @p__linq__3 ESCAPE '~') 
AND ([Extent1].[text] LIKE @p__linq__4 ESCAPE '~')
```

--should be

```
WHERE ([Extent1].[score] = @p__linq__0) 
AND ([Extent1].[date_created] >= @p__linq__1) 
AND ([Extent1].[date_created] <= @p__linq__2) 
AND (([Extent1].[text] LIKE @p__linq__3 ESCAPE '~') 
    OR ([Extent1].[text] LIKE @p__linq__4 ESCAPE '~'))
```

I hope someone can help me as I've spent a couple of hours now searching for a solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the problem and what does it mean: //how to use OR for each in array?

Comment: You might want to have a look at the Specification Pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern . A simple implementation of the pattern can be found here https://github.com/pmacn/Specific

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have guessed, this is the part with the problem that you will need to change, because it will "AND" all of the clauses.

```
//how to use OR for each in array?
foreach (var keyword in keywords)
{
    var keywordCondition = keyword;
    query = query.Where(x => x.text.Contains(keywordCondition));  
}
```

I think you can do that by changing it to:

```
query = query.Where(x => keywords.Any(kw => x.text.Contains(kw));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should really look into Dynamic LINQ queries ( explained very well here - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library)

You can specify your query like below -

```
.Where("Column1 = value1 OR Column2 = value2");
```

Comment: While I like and have used dynamic LINQ, I don't think it's necessary or appropriate here. They just need an `Any` clause instead of the loop.

Comment: wouldn't this create a threat for SQL Injection??

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if there is a cleaner way, but change

```
foreach (var keyword in keywords)
    {
        var keywordCondition = keyword;
        query = query.Where(x => x.text.Contains(keywordCondition));  
    }
```

to

```
query = query.Where(x => keywords.Any(k => x.text.Contains(k));
```

`Any()` will return a bool if `x.text` contains any of the keywords in the list

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to build the predicate (condition) dynamically the easiest and most flexible way I've found of doing that is to use the PredicateBuilder.

http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

It gives you full control over whether you are using an `and` or an `or` to build up the query.